# Streaming Facebook Pages Wall (not just the pages posts)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I have looked on 100 forums looking for a simple answer for how to stream every post on a Facebook page's wall (not using the like box for just the pages posts, but everyone's posts). I am the admin of the page and I am already using the like box for my posts so I understand that, however the developer pages of Facebook are too confusing for such a simple task. I will be inserting the stream into an HTML page which will be hosted on www.1and1.com so it can handle most, if not all code.

I know it is a lot to ask but is there evem someplace online that will offer plain step-by-step instructions for my specific needs?

Comment: AFAIK currently not possible.

Comment: @Rufinus it isn't possible to stream a pages wall? i know you can stream your personal wall and the pages posts on the pages wall. But not a combination of the two?

"Real-Time Subscriptions

The Page object supports Real-time Updates for feed, picture, tagged and checkins connections."

Comment: i was under the impression its currently no longer possible to get posts from other users on your fan-page wall, but as @OffBySome proofs, it is working. (maybe there was a bug as i last tried it) but All will not work, i'm not sure but i think its only the last 100 posts or so.

Comment: @Rufinus - they started requiring access tokens recently for /page/posts so that may be the bug you were thinking of?

Comment: @OffBySome no, i used a application token, but then again, the change a lot, not sure if it really was the /feed endpoint.

Comment: @Rufinus the last 100 posts are more than enough. Im kind of taking the idea of having a "forum" for a live event, which facebook offers but I want it to be through my page so people can just post on my page or go to my website. I now have the pull thanks to OffBySome but now I just need to take that and display it on an html page. Also it isn't just one live event, I want it to be year-round.   

ps. you guys rock!

Answer (score 1):

If the social plugins they make available aren't sufficient, you could just pull in the feed with the Facebook graph api using the javascript sdk (easiest) or there is probably an SDK for whatever programming language you know.  For example, you can see a list of posts on the coca cola page using the Facebook graph explorer:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=cocacola%2Ffeed

The /page/feed method needs an access token, but you can use the graph explorer to get an offline_access token that you can use to pull the data in. This may eliminate javascript sdk usage though unless you want to first prompt users to authenticate your application.  But otherwise you would just parse the json feed that is returned in the url indicated in the graph explorer (and add your access_token to the end of the url).

Comment: oooh, yeah using my ID and the access token that https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ created for me, I could pull the feed. I know java, html, and php decently so should I just use the javascript sdk? where can I find the information on this? I have absolutely no experience in pulling a feed (thanks to you I kind of know!) and putting it into a html page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [good PHP tutorial](http://ranacse05.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/show-facebook-group-wall-on-web-site/) on how to display a groups feed on a web page. It would be just as easy to display the posts from a page (since you are the admin)

Just replace the group ID with the page ID. Here is a link to the feed for the Facebook [Platform feed graph api results](https://graph.facebook.com/platform/feed?access_token=2227470867%7C2.AQBOlbqc5rPOnqqM.3600.1310101200.0-113652%7C9ALP4POJsHIRdqAQv6875q2j1a4). More info on [FB Pages here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/).